# Run capybara test against my staging server

Tags: rake, capybara

I'm new to capybara, and really happy with it's capabilities, I got a few feature tests that runs on my build server in a test environment.

I'm thinking it'll be a good practice to make some other set of tests that would run after a new version is published to my staging server (where the QA doing it's tests)

I need this tests to run on a remote server(does not look like an issue) and I need them to run on the staging environment.

How do I run one set of tests on the staging env and another on the test ?

Can I make a task for the staging?

Comment: Did you made any progress with this?

Comment: Yes actually, check out testim.io its simple and just works!

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this.  One would be to create a separate directory for tests against staging and then have RSpec run the tests in that directory when you want to test staging.  Another would be to tag the features (or scenarios) for staging with   staging: true metadata or something

```
feature 'these tests are done in staging', staging: true do
  ...
end
```

and then run rspec with -t staging (which you could set up in your Rakefile).